# If $R$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $m$ then show that $R_m \cong R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

If $R$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $m$ then show that $R_m \cong R$.

I know that maximals ideals are prime and every element in $R \setminus m$ is a unit, but how can I use this to solve the question?

Comment: Check that $ R $ satisfies the universal property of localization. Intuitively, localization at $ m $ adds inverses for every element in $ R $ that is not in $ m $; however, if $ R $ is already local with maximal ideal $ m $, then anything not in $ m $ is already invertible, which means localizing at $ m $ gets you nothing new.

Comment: @Starfall What is the universal property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $R$ is local, every element of $R\setminus M$ is an unit.

For any $\frac{r}{s}\in R_M$, map $\frac{r}{s}\mapsto rs^{-1}$. (If $s$ were not already a unit of $R$, this would not be possible.)

You can work to confirm that this map is

1. well-defined
2. a ring homomorphism
3. a bijection

Comment: Is the map from R_m to R?

Comment: @Bob yes, $R_M$ to $R$.  You don't have to find the inverse to prove it is a bijection. Just show it is one-to-one and onto.

Comment: @Bob you can show $r\mapsto r/1$ is the inverse, also. The idea is that every $r/s$ is equivalent to $rs^{-1}/1$, and $Rs^{-1}=R$, multiplying by a unit  doesn't change much

Comment: For well defined: I show that if $r/u=r'/u'$ then $ru^{-1}=r'u'^{-1}$?

Comment: @bob You are correct for the well-defined comment.

Comment: For Injectivity, show the kernel is zero. Surjectiveity is obvious if you think about it!

Comment: You got Injectivity. Can't you see what happens with $r/1$ for surjectivity?

Comment: @bob yes, except for one missing prime on an r. I don't understand your confusion on surjectivity. If you know $r/1$ maps to $r$ for any $r\in R$, that is already surjectivity.

Comment: @Bob No, because every $r$ has a preimage in $R_M$... That is the definition of surjectivity. Dunno what u you are thinking of.

Comment: I get it now thanks.

Comment: We can also just see that the natural map $R \to R_M$ is bijective.

Comment: @AlJebr Tomato tomahto.